# Where to place static-nodes.json for geth

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, peers, enode

I am setting up a private Ethereum network using `puppeth` whic creates the sealer nodes on various servers.

To aid peer discovery, it has been suggested that we include a list of `enodes` in the file `static-nodes.json` for `geth` to use.

Where do we place `static-nodes.json`?

1. The datadir directory containing folders `geth` and `keystore, and the file`geth.ipc`
2. The datadir/geth directory containing folders `chaindata`, `lightchaindata`, `nodes`, and the files `LOCK`, `nodekey`, `transactions.rlp`?

Additionally, where do we place `trusted-nodes.json`? Can we let `geth` use both files `trusted-nodes.json` and `static-nodes.json`, or must we choose one of the two to use?

Does the nodes added using `admin.addPeer` gets stored somewhere, or must we re-add these nodes again if we restart `geth`?

Comment: You've got too many questions. Split them up to increase the chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Where do we place static-nodes.json? Additionally, where do we place trusted-nodes.json?

If you specify `--datadir=./` when running your node, the files: `static-nodes.json` and `trusted-nodes.json` should be in the current directory.

If for example you do not specify the datadir directory, place the files next to the `nodekey`, `keystore` folders (on the same level)

> Does the nodes added using admin.addPeer gets stored somewhere, or must we re-add these nodes again if we restart geth?

Using `admin.addPeer` is volatile, it will not be persisted on the disk.

Comment: If you do not specify a directory, will the datadir be `~/.ethereum`? In this case, you will add `static-nodes.json` to `~/.ethereum`, but in my case my directory has the directories `geth` and `keystore`, but `nodekey` file is inside the `geth` folder. Where then should I place `static-nodes.json`?

Comment: @AthenaWisdom any resolution or workaround? I have the same question, and I'm thinking just put it in both places using a symlink.

Comment: It worked for me in the `geth` folder, so next to `nodekey` file, not next to `keystore` folder which is in the `datadir` folder (or `~/.ethereum` in your case).